# is there a name for sum of elements lower/upper-half of a dataset?

Tags: terminology

Given a dataset, the median separates the dataset into the lower half and the upper half.

Is there a name for the sum of the lower half and the sum of the upper half?

E.g. $D = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5 \}$, median is $3$, lower half would be $L :=\{1, 2 \}$ and upper half is $U:=\{4, 5\}$.

It there a name for $\sum_{i \in L} i$ and $\sum_{j \in U} j $ ?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by the "sum" of halves of datasets.  Their union? The sum of all their values? The two sums of their values separately? Something else?  BTW, the upper and lower halves usually *include* the median when there are an odd number of values.

Comment: so the sum refers to the sum of elements. thanks for pointing out, updated the question

Comment: Not sure this helps much, but each is a trimmed sum associated with a suitably general definition of a trimmed mean.

Comment: The version of this for random variables would be *partial moments*.